# PayPal's Adaptive Payments API and chained payments with installments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I own a website where sellers can sell their items (pretty much a market place). The thing is that now **I would like to provide the buyer the option to pay with installments**. I know sellers can configure their installment plans in their PayPal panel, and I would like those settings to be valid to the chained payments I create through the Adaptive Payments API.
However, when a user is redirected to the payment page of a created payment, **they do not see the option to pay with installments**.
I am not very experienced with PayPal's API, but the only way I've found to partially solve this is to implement installments planning in my website (both to the buyer and the seller) and simulate installments with preapproved payments. This wouldn't guarantee the money in the seller's PayPal's account right away, however. So there I have one big question (and a smaller one):

- How can I provide the option to use installments through the Adaptive Payments API?

If there is no way to do what I ask above: then are there any restrictions on what fees I can charge for my service in case I choose to simulate installments with preapproved payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question probably won't serve many people: it only concerns Brazilian customers.
Installments are a must-have in the brazilian market and so the option to enable them for customers is available for free in PayPal for brazilian sellers. Yet, when a payment is created through the Adaptive Payments API, it really does not respect the seller's installment plan, giving the buyer no option to buy with installments.
I have contacted PayPal's support on this and it seems to be a real issue (i.e. not a problem with how I'm doing it). Although they are looking into it, there is no expected time for this to fixed.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Marcelo, do you found a solution to use paypal adaptive payments together with installments?

Comment: Sadly, we discontinued our product long ago. I probably have all exchanged emails with PayPal with me if it helps, but I really don't know the state of things right now.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am talking to their support and trying to search other options other than paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout PayPal [Enhanced Recurring Payments](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview) product - it does provide a good solution for collecting installments.

Comment: Buyers can already choose to pay with installments when I use the "Create button" functionality inside PayPal. I want to be able to use the Adaptive Payments API to generate a payment that can be paid with installments (is this possible with the aforementioned product? Is it **only** possible with it?)